# showing cast error for _id but id is never used node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been working on node and mongo for a while now but this problem is not getting solved now coming on to the problem:
Here is my code:

```
router.get('/getLocBJ', function(req, res) {
    mongoose.model('Locations').find({
    }, function(err, locations) {
        res.format({
            json: function() {
                res.json(locations);
            }
        });
    }).limit(500);
});
```

Whenever I call this API 
what I expect: It should return 500 rows from the collection
What's happening: It's showing me this error:

```
GET Error: There was a problem retrieving: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "getLocBJ" at path "_id"
```

What I did before: I was trying to return some specific values like "_id, lat & lng" since then it's showing the same error even removing the culprit code from the function not seems to be working.
tried clearing system cache but no success.

Edit the schema used:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  trackernumber: String,
  cdate : String,
  accountId : String,     
  time : String,       
  speed : String,    
  lat : String,
  lng : String,    
  orientation:String,
  createdDate:Date,
  rowData:{},
  alarm_code : String,
  distance : String,
  alarm : {},
  locFlag : String    
});
mongoose.model('Locations', locationSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after spending more than 2 days on this thing, fortunately, I solved this problem. 
It was happening with all the **get** APIs I was developing in recent times.

How I solved this,

this is kind of weird solution though don't know how it worked
(so what I did please have a look at the code for the same):

```
 router.get('/:id/getLocBJ', function(req, res) {
    mongoose.model('Locations').find({
    }, function(err, locations) {
        res.format({
            json: function() {
                res.json(locations);
            }
        });
    }).limit(500);
});
```

I just added a **get** param '/:id' in the API call:

```
router.get('/:id/getLocBJ', function(req, res) {
```

and the error flew away I'm still not getting how it worked.

If anyone can help elaborate this that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can try This one:

```
router.get('/getLocBJ', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('Locations').find().limit(500).exec(function(err, locations) {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).send({msg: 'Error occurred'});
    }
    return res.status(200).send(locations);
  });
});
```

and export your model using `module.exports` because you used as `mongoose.model('Locations')` otherwise you may got error.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Locations', locationSchema);
```

N.B: If you added `_id` value manually or when you create using model then delete that document first. `_id` generate automatically so you don't need to add manually or in schema

Comment: The _id field is autogenerated I haven't added it manually & for the code you've suggested I tried using that but still the same result.

Comment: this error generally occurred for `findById` method not for `find` so should be work my query. just you need to `export` your model